# programmatically create panel and add picture boxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to programmatically create a panel and add some pictureBoxes where i select the image through a for loop. I tried lots of ways but the form shows empty.
My code is :

```
private void draw_pipeline()
    {

        Panel pnl = new Panel();

        pnl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1130, 145);
        pnl.Location = new Point(380, 260);
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        for (int i =0; i<3; i++)
        {

            PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
            pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: 
                    { 
                    pic.Location = new Point(3, 15); 
                    pic.Size = new Size(73, 121);
                    pic.Image = new Bitmap("if.png"); break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        pic.Location = new Point(76, 15); 
                        pic.Size = new Size(73, 121);
                        pic.Image = new Bitmap("line.png"); break;
                    }
            }
            pnl.Controls.Add(pic);
        }


    }
```

the result i want to create is illustrated in the picture below, that contains two picture boxes with two images, if.png which is the if-box image and the line.png which is the line image. I repeat the result of my code is that form shows empty!! Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add the `Panel` to the `Form` at some point, in the same way you're adding `PictureBoxes` to the `Panel`:

```
this.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

(The `this` is assuming that your `draw_pipeline` method belongs to the `Form` to which you're trying to add the `Panel`.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm trying that and i'll keep you inform if i need further help!