# How i create user panel using multiple panel

Tags: c#

I want to create a panel listing everyone connected to a socket. So i create something like that for create the first panel and add another one with new pos (X: lastY+0 Y: lastY+88)

i used this example for do my
code [programmatically create panel and add picture boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255438/programmatically-create-panel-and-add-picture-boxes)

```
        int numberOfConnected = 5;

        int panelSizeX = 776;
        int panelSizeY = 75;

        int lastPanelX = 0;
        int lastPanelY = 0;
        int firstPanelX = 0;
        int firstPanelY = 0;

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        //Retry create a panel and place it while i <= numberOfConnected
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfConnected; i++)
        {
            if(firstPanelX == 0 && firstPanelY == 0)
            {
                firstPanelX = 12;
                firstPanelY = 12;

                panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(panelSizeX, panelSizeY);
                panel.Location = new Point(firstPanelX, firstPanelY);
                panel.BackColor = new System.Drawing.Color(26, 26, 26); // Idk how to import a color so a error is here
            }
            else
            {
                panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(panelSizeX, panelSizeY);
                panel.Location = new Point(lastPanelX, lastPanelY + 88); //Define new panel pos
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Sounds like something like this: [Continuous Scrolling with Panels in Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748522)

Comment: Yeah it do, i just want to add panels every Y+88 and if possible scoll on the page

Comment: `panel.Location = new Point(lastPanelX, lastPanelY + 88);` You never change `lastPanelY`. You can try `panel.Location = new Point(lastPanelX, firstPanelY + 88 * i);`

Comment: Adding panels is same as adding buttons.  See my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You never change `lastPanelY` in the loop.
- `for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfConnected; i++)` looks like an error. Use `<` ?
- You need to create a new panel each iteration.
- You need to add the new panel to some parent control.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Panel parent;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        parent = new Panel();
        parent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(parent);

        CreatePanels();
    }

    void CreatePanels()
    {
        int numberOfConnected = 5;

        var panelSize = new Size(776, 75);
        var panelPos = new Point(12, 12);
        int panelVertOffset = 88;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfConnected; i++)
        {
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Size = panelSize;
            panel.Location = panelPos;
            panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 26, 26);
            parent.Controls.Add(panel);

            panelPos.Offset(0, panelVertOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you plan to do with these panels, you might want to use a custom control instead.

Comment: Johnny Mopp It don't seem work for me. I don't have error it's just lag my app and not showing.

Comment: jdweng i don't understand your example. What is the point with my question

Comment: @IdkWhatShouldIUse I have updated to a full [mre]. It works fine for me.